# Iptables not forward traffic

Tags: iptables

I need to redirect all traffic incoming on port 9750 (the port chat server) to another machine on the same subnet. Ports clients - dynamic.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d x.x.x.a --dport 9750 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.b:9750
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 9750 -j MASQUERADE
```

However, the `host x.x.x.a` does not open port 9750. Clients do not connect to the server.

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf |grep forward
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

Comment: Problem was solved. Helped the following commands:

    iptables -A FORWARD -d x.x.x.b -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9750 -j ACCEPT &&

    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d x.x.x.a -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9750 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.b &&

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your intentions were with `x.x.x.a` and `x.x.x.b`.  For the PREROUTING rule you need to specify the external interface and the internal machine's IP:Port.

For port forwarding you don't need a MASQUERADE rule.  However, you do need a rule to allow the traffic on the FORWARD chain.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i [external_iface] -p [proto] --dport [external_port] -j DNAT --to [internal_ip]:[internal_port]
iptables -A FORWARD -p [proto] -d [internal_ip] --dport [internal_port] -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 9750 -j DNAT --to x.x.x.b  

    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d x.x.x.b --dport 9750 -j ACCEPT  

does not work

Comment: you're missing the port for the PREROUTING rule, it should be `x.x.x.b:port`

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide packet forwarding configuration, so I hope you missed it. Temporarily you can enable it by:-

```
 echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To make it permanent open /etc/sysctl.conf and provide this parameter:-

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 


      1

Comment: ok then the chat server, is it tcp itself? I think now its time to do some debugging.